# Project level connections missing from packages after copying solution

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2019

I have an SSIS solution (with multiple packages) in Visual Studio 2019 that is using the Project Deployment model. I wanted to move it to another folder to match our current development practices here. I copied the entire folder structure to a new location, but now when I open the solution all of the connections are missing. I had been using two project-level connections that were shared by all of the packages. I can still see them in the Connection Managers as part of the project tree in the Solution Explorer, but they no longer show up in the Connection Managers tab for each package and all of the packages report errors in any item that was using a connection because the connection no longer exists.

[image]

I've noticed that when I right-click on the SSIS Packages folder in the Solution Explorer that the menu item to update all packages to the Project Deployment model is there (even though they were all set to that previously), but if I try to do that the missing connection errors prevent it.

I've check the GUID values for the connections and they match what are in the .conmgr files, but the individual packages aren't seeing them. If I go into the individual items the drop down lists to select a connection don't show my connections (which makes sense because they aren't listed in the package connection manager).

Any suggestions on how to get past this? I could have sworn that I had copied a solution folder previously with no problems.

As a side-note, is there a setting in the XML files that tells Visual Studio whether the packages are the project vs. the package deployment model?

Thanks for any help that you can give!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the issue was the .vs hidden folder being copied along with everything else. That folder included a .suo file which had hard-coded paths to the connection managers. This was throwing off the whole build and breaking it. I recopied without including the .vs folder and it worked like a charm.